# Do we need to recompile .asp files?

Tags: asp-classic

I made some changes to the existing asp page. When I access it I don't see the changes yet and I still see the old content. Do I need to recompile .asp files?

Answer (score 3):

The pages are likely cached in your browser.  There are a number of ways to get around this.  You can:

- force a page refresh on the browser ([Ctrl]+[F5])
- Recycle the application pool (if this is an application)
- (or the dirty way) make a tiny change (like adding a space) to the global.asa which will in turn recycle the app pool

### Edit (2017)

If you're debugging using IE then you can also set your cache to refresh every time you visit the page:

Bring up the internet options. Click the **Settings** button on the **Browsing history** section of the dialog and change the **Check for newer versions of the stored pages:** setting to **Every time I visit the webpage**...

[image: Example of]

Answer (score 2):

ASP pages are scripting , you do not need to compile , just check if you have page cached on the browser .

Comment: @Westie In ASP.Net, but not for Classic ASP pages.

Comment: @AnonJr yes you can compile [Classic ASP](http://aspclassiccompiler.codeplex.com/) or even [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/lichen/archive/2011/03/30/asp-classic-compiler-is-now-open-source.aspx).

Comment: @Westie which is great if you're working in .Net, but not if you need to run as a classic page - which is what the original question sounds like.

Comment: Apologies - I can't tell if we're arguing at cross purposes here.  What I'm getting at is that classic ASP pages can be compiled (see links in previous comments) though it does compile to a .NET executable, and yes - the files are of a .asp extension, not .aspx.